# "keep-alive" header on connections created by keycloak's java adapter

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, keycloak

I'm using Keycloak's java adapter in an application and would like to ensure that all the connections in the connection pool maintained by the adapter have "keep-alive" strategy when created.

Is there a way through configuration (or even changing the code) to do this?

Comment: For anyone interested, there is no way to do this, even with the latest version of keycloak's adapter. I'm gonna make a pull request for keycloak exposing a parameter for http client builder using which the consumer can control the keep-alive strategy.

Comment: Is this issue fixed now? I am also facing the same issue and could see more ports are in CLOSE_WAIT condition. Any input would be helpful.

Comment: @Balachandar The only way I fixed this was to fork the keycloak's git repo internally and add the ability for ourselves to pass a value for the keep-alive property of the underlying HttpClient through the keycloak's Java client. That allowed us to configure keep-alive from the client side and close the connection cleanly. Sadly, I never got to make a PR for the keycloak team, but now that I see there are more interests, I'm gonna do that.

Comment: can you help me do it. I cloned repo, i would like to know where to add the keepalive. I am using keycloak-spring-security-adapter.

Comment: in "keycloak-adapter-core" project edit the class HttpClientBuilder. Find "DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);" line and use the "client" object's "setKeepAliveStrategy" method to inject your instance of ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy which uses a client side parameter. Apache's default implementation of "ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy" interface only looks for the "keep-alive" header in the response.

Comment: Thank you Amir. Hope you would raise a pull request as it might be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone not wanting to fork the Keycloak library, you can alter the client after the KeycloakDeploymentBuilder builds your KeycloakDeployment instance.

The code below will cause a default keep-alive strategy of 60 seconds as long as the DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy does not find a value greater than 0 in any "Keep-Alive" headers returned to the client.

Keep in mind that this value is not used by the underlying DefaultRequestDirector if the reuseStrategy is not returning true.  This is controlled by the "Connection: keep-alive" header in the response.  You could also create code to set a default for the reuseStrategy as well if needed.

```
final KeycloakDeployment keycloakDeployment = KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(config);


final long connectionTimeOutSeconds = 60;
final HttpClient client = keycloakDeployment.getClient();
if(client instanceof AbstractHttpClient) {
    ((AbstractHttpClient) client).setKeepAliveStrategy(new CustomConnectionKeepAliveStrategy(connectionTimeOutSeconds));
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

public class CustomConnectionKeepAliveStrategy extends DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy {


   private final long defaultKeepAliveDurationInSeconds;

   public CustomConnectionKeepAliveStrategy(long defaultKeepAliveDurationInSeconds) {
       this.defaultKeepAliveDurationInSeconds = defaultKeepAliveDurationInSeconds;
   }

   @Override
   public long getKeepAliveDuration(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
       long keepAliveDuration = super.getKeepAliveDuration(response, context);

       if(keepAliveDuration > 0) {
           return keepAliveDuration;
       }

       return defaultKeepAliveDurationInSeconds * 1000;
   }
}
```

It should also be noted that the Keycloak server I work with returns a Connection: keep-alive header, so my connections were already being reused.  My problem was that the default behavior is then to keep connections alive forever. This was causing issues as our firewall with Kubernetes Ingress was dropping the connection and our application was then intermittently failing to talk to Keycloak.  The above code causes the connections to be thrown away when they become stale (older than 1 minutes in our case).  The underlying Java http libraries will update the connection's expiry date so that connections which were recently used do not get thrown away.